# probability that a random finite string is a true mathematical statement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Lets say that we form the space of strings of length $n$ where each string is composed by a sequence of symbols and each symbol may be $[0, \dots, 9]$ or any special character $[+, -, =, \times, \div, <, >]$. Also, the space of possible strings is restricted in a way that no special charcter can be in the first or last position of the string, or next to another special character. By last, at least one relational operator must belong to the string.

Can the probability of deciding whether a random string from the space is a TRUE statement be computed in any other way that doesn't involve generating all possible strings and counting which ones are true?

Comment: That cannot be calculated because there are true statements not yet proven which cannot be included in the analysis.

Comment: I don't think Godel's incompleteness theorem applies here.

Comment: If you get rid of the condition that you must have at least one $=$ sign, the problem becomes much more tractable, since then every comparison has a $1/3$ chance of being true.

Comment: Yeah, i'll edit the question to the condition that there must be at least one relational operator

Comment: @JosephCamacho I didn't mean Godel incompleteness. I was imagining some specific statement which at some time in the future is proved by someone, but for now is not known to be true. For such a statement, one could not decide at present whether to include it among the true statements.

Comment: If you want to restrict the strings to all sensible statements, you need a bit more, as e.g. $02=2$ is quite an ambiguous mathematical statement. Counting the total number of valid $n$-length strings is quite difficult, but that would be the denominator of our probability.